# Javascript unit testing - using Jasmine to spy on self-invoking function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

With a javascript construct like this:

```
var myClass = function(myArgumentObject) {

    var vm = {
        myFunction: myFunction,
        myVariable: myVariable
    }
    return vm;

    myFunction() {
        myVariable = 1 + 1;
        myArgumentObject.aMethod();
    }

} (myArgumentObject);
```

How (if at all) can one use the Jasmine framework to spy on (i.e. mock out) myArgumentObject so that one can unit test myFunction?

Doing this:

```
it('test myFunction', function () {
    myClass.myFunction();
    expect(myClass.myVariable).toEqual(2);
});
```

Fails because there's an error when it tries to call a method on myArgumentObject. I know I can create a fake version of myArgumentObject with jasmine.createSpy but I can't see how you pass it in.

Comment: Shouldn't the function return `vm`?

Comment: Yes, it should. Just missed in constructing the pseudo-code. Will add now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Great question!  Testing is key.

You can define your arguments/input within your test:

```
it ('test myClass function', function() {
    myArgumentObject = function() {
        this.aMethod: jasmine.createSpy();
    };
    // mock out initial values for your other variables here, eg myVariable

    spyOn(vm, 'myFunction').andCallThrough();

    myClass(myArgumentObject)

    expect(myArgumentObject.aMethod).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(vm.myVariable).toEqual(2)
});
```

A couple things to keep in mind -- Your 'return vm' statement will cut your function off early -- you won't need it.

You should define your variables early so that you don't get an error.  Consider moving myFunction above the 'vm' object.

Answer (score 0):

So I assume the following, you have  a global variable called `myArgumentObject` which have function `aMethod`. Then you can spy on this function using jasmine like this.

```
it('test myFunction', function () {
  spyOn(myArgumentObject, 'aMethod')
  myClass.myFunction();
  expect(myClass.myVariable).toEqual(2);
});
```

But if there is no gloabl variable you cant test this, cause then `undefined` is passed to the test and it will always fail, as you can't change private variables in the scope of the function.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But myArgumentObject is a global variable inside myClass. But it isn't available in the test class. So doing what you're suggesting above leads to either "spyOn could not find an object to spy upon" or "can't find variable myArgumentObject" errors depending on whether I use the object's namespace or not.